# Sorting comments from newest to oldest

Tags: 8, comments

How should I configure Drupal 8 to sort comments from newest to oldest, similarly to what the *Comment Goodness* module does in Drupal 7?

Comment: Find some clue: \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder::viewMultiple but still didn't know how to order

Answer (score 5):

As `CommentStorage::loadThread` adds `comment_filter` tag to its query, you may use [`hook_query_TAG_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/8.2.x) hook to change comments order:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter() for comment_filter tag.
 *
 * @see CommentStorage::loadThread().
 */
function mymodule_query_comment_filter_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  // Change comment order to DESC for 'comment' field.
  if ($query->getMetaData('field_name') == 'comment') {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Query\SelectInterface $query */
    $order_by = &$query->getOrderBy();
    // 'c.cid' is for flat comment lists.
    if (isset($order_by['c.cid']) && $order_by['c.cid'] == 'ASC') {
      $order_by['c.cid'] = 'DESC';
    }
    // 'torder' is for threated comment lists.
    if (isset($order_by['torder']) && $order_by['torder'] == 'ASC') {
      $order_by['torder'] = 'DESC';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stanislav Agapov

I had to modify your code. For me works this one:

```if ($query->getMetaData('field_name') == 'comment') {
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Query\SelectInterface $query */
        $order_by = &$query->getOrderBy();
        if (isset($order_by['torder']) && $order_by['torder'] == 'ASC') {
            $order_by['torder'] = 'DESC';
        }
    }```

Comment: @seb your solution works for threaded commens. For flat comment lists works mine. I updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: your solution for threaded comments is not going to sort properly, making latest replies visually appear above parent comments.

@echo's approach with unsetting `toroder` and sorting by `thread` worked

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your comment field's machine name is **field_comments**, put this code into a module to get descending comments. I was having trouble with threaded comments, but this works since it alters the query by the c.thread database column instead of just 'torder'

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter() for comment_filter tag.
 *
 * @see CommentStorage::loadThread().
 */
function MYMODULE_query_comment_filter_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {

  // Change comment order to DESC for 'comment' field.
  if ($query->getMetaData('field_name') == 'field_comments') {

    $order_by = &$query->getOrderBy();
    $expressions = &$query->getExpressions();
    // Sorting for threaded comments.
    if (isset($order_by['torder']) && $order_by['torder'] == 'ASC') {
      // Get rid of the expressions that prepare the threads for ASC ordering.
      unset($expressions['torder']);
      unset($order_by['torder']);
      // Simply order by the thread field.
      $order_by['c.thread'] = 'DESC';
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: This is the properly working solution for threaded comments. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could create a comments view and sort them there.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8 you can use the next module: Comments order.

Link: https://www.drupal.org/project/comments_order

> This module provides to change comments order (sorting functionality)
>   in Drupal 8. You can pick comment order (newest first or oldest first)
>   per node type, editing your comment type field on the "Manage fields"
>   tab (node type administration page).
>
> Not only in flat, but also in threaded display! If you use threaded
>   display, you can pick how will able to sort children comments.
>   Examples below.

Answer (score 0):

core/modules/comment/src/CommentStorage.php line 302. I think the only way is hack the core! & only for FLAT module.

```
    if ($mode == CommentManagerInterface::COMMENT_MODE_FLAT) {
  $query->orderBy('c.cid', 'DESC');
}
else {
  // See comment above. Analysis reveals that this doesn't cost too
  // much. It scales much much better than having the whole comment
  // structure.
  $query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(c.thread, 1, (LENGTH(c.thread) - 1))', 'torder');
  $query->orderBy('torder', 'ASC');
}
```

Comment: There is no need to hack core when an entity definition can be altered.